# Display several time series in same Excel chart

Tags: excel, charts, time-series

I have some time series data in a CSV file: three columns Date, Value, and Name as follows. I thought that it would be easy to open this in Excel and create a chart on which there would be three lines: one for each of Alice, Bob, and Carol which plotted the Value (on the y-axis) against the timestamp (on the x-axis). However, I cannot work out how to do this. Am I missing something obvious?

```
Thu Dec 17 21:28:48 PST 2020,84664,Alice

Thu Dec 17 21:28:48 PST 2020,5336,Bob

Thu Dec 17 21:28:10 PST 2020,87332,Alice

Thu Dec 17 21:28:10 PST 2020,2668,Bob

Thu Dec 17 21:25:58 PST 2020,43666,Alice

Thu Dec 17 21:25:58 PST 2020,46334,Bob

Thu Dec 17 21:25:11 PST 2020,47866,Alice

Thu Dec 17 21:25:11 PST 2020,42134,Bob

Thu Dec 17 21:24:24 PST 2020,1794,Carol

Thu Dec 17 21:24:24 PST 2020,46072,Alice

Thu Dec 17 21:24:24 PST 2020,42134,Bob

Thu Dec 17 21:23:01 PST 2020,5994,Carol

Thu Dec 17 21:23:01 PST 2020,62872,Alice

Thu Dec 17 21:23:01 PST 2020,21134,Bob

Thu Dec 17 21:21:24 PST 2020,10194,Carol

Thu Dec 17 21:21:24 PST 2020,41872,Alice

Thu Dec 17 21:21:24 PST 2020,37934,Bob

Thu Dec 17 21:20:43 PST 2020,12294,Carol

Thu Dec 17 21:20:43 PST 2020,39772,Alice

Thu Dec 17 21:20:43 PST 2020,37934,Bob

Thu Dec 17 21:19:10 PST 2020,24894,Carol
```

Thanks for any help, Martin

Comment: One way is to pivot data, add names to columns field, dates to row field, and values to value field. Then you will end up with 3 series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to create a pivot table from these columns and use `Name` as Columns and `Datetime` as Rows.

[image]

Then, go to `Insert` - `Charts` - Select the chart you want to apply (example below)

[image]

Comment: Perfect - this was very helpful. Thank you! Martin